# PHP script can't insert into database

Tags: php

it keeps telling me that it couldn't insert into the database. 
Can someone outline what i've done wrong? i've never had any problems until now.

```
<html>
 <title>Server logs</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-color:#fff;
font-family:tahoma;
}
</style>
<body>
<center>
<h3>Server updates</h3>
<?php
//variables for connecting.
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="aion";
$db="website";
//connection to the server.
$con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if($con)
{
echo "Connection: <font color='lime'>Connected to the database</font><br>";
}
else{
echo "Connection: <font color='red'>Couldn't connect to the database</font><br>";
}
$select=mysql_select_db($db);
if($select)
{
echo "Db status: <font color='lime'>Selected the db successfully</font>";
}
else{
echo "Db status: <font color='red'>couldn't select the database</font>";
}
?>
<br><br>
<form action="" method="post">
<table width="300" style="text-align:center;">
<tr>
<td>Username: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your name here"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Update: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="update" placeholder="Enter update information here"        style="width:300px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<p>This was made so we can keep track of the updates we do to the server.</p>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if(!empty($_POST['username'] && !empty($_POST['update'])))
{
//the information that we passed from the 2 textboxes
$name=$_POST['username'];
$update=$_POST['update'];
//variables for connecting.
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="aion";
$db="website";
//connection to the server.
$con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
//running a query to insert the previous information gathered into the database.
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs (name,update) VALUES ('$name','$update') ");
//running an if statement to see if the info was inserted, if it was it will display that it was      inserted else display that it wasn't.
if($sql)
{
echo "Successfully inserted the update";
}
else{
echo "There was an error inserting the info into the database";
}
}
else
{
echo "no information was entered! Please go back and input some information";
}
} 

?>
</body>
</html>    `
```

Comment: Check `mysql_error`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score 0):

the password for making the connection to the database is given by you is correct ?

for localhost we always use `blank` password. If credentials is given by you is correct. Then enable the **PHP errors** and **mysql errors** .

**Php errors :**

```
ini_set('display_errors', True);
```

**Mysql errors :**

```
mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work..
that is not working because you have a 'update' column which is a reserved word so you must put like this

```
 `INSERT INTO logs (name,`update`) VALUES ('$name','$update')`
```

and some of your codes has missing parenthesis

```
    <html>
    <title>Server logs</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
    background-color:#fff;
    font-family:tahoma;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <center>
    <h3>Server updates</h3>
    <?php
    //variables for connecting.
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="aion";
$db="website";
    //connection to the server.
    $con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    if($con)
    {
    echo "Connection: <font color='lime'>Connected to the database</font><br>";
    }
    else{
    echo "Connection: <font color='red'>Couldn't connect to the database</font><br>";
    }

    $select=mysql_select_db($db);
    if($select)
    {
    echo "Db status: <font color='lime'>Selected the db successfully</font>";
    }
    else{
    echo "Db status: <font color='red'>couldn't select the database</font>";
    }
    ?>
    <br><br>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table width="300" style="text-align:center;">
    <tr>
    <td>Username: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your name here"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Update: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="update" placeholder="Enter update information here"        style="width:300px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <p>This was made so we can keep track of the updates we do to the server.</p>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['update']))
    {
    //the information that we passed from the 2 textboxes
    $name=$_POST['username'];
    $update=$_POST['update'];
    //variables for connecting.
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $db="website";
    //connection to the server.
    $con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db);
    //running a query to insert the previous information gathered into the database.
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs (name,`update`) VALUES ('$name','$update') ");
    //running an if statement to see if the info was inserted, if it was it will display that it was      inserted else display that it wasn't.
    if($sql)
    {
    echo "Successfully inserted the update";
    }
    else{
    echo "There was an error inserting the info into the database";
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "no information was entered! Please go back and input some information";
    }
    } 

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this works =) because i test this before i post.. =))